# How to optimise similar queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Often, I end up using several similar queries in my Django views, with one varying lookup field.

This accumulate easily, and lead to severe impacts on page load times. How can one go about optimising this?

```
{
    "pg1": Product.objects.filter(groups__group="pg1")[:5],
    "pg2": Product.objects.filter(groups__group="pg2")[:5],
    "pg3": Product.objects.filter(groups__group="pg3")[:5],
    "pg4": Product.objects.filter(groups__group="pg4")[:5],
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [using a cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, using a cache would help provide some optimisation, but I was looking to reduce the number of queries made to the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly you are writing query for each page? what happens when you have 100's of pages? **No, That's not the way you do it!**

Use `django.core.paginator` in django which helps you manage pagination for your views. 
More information could be found here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/

Comment: No, I am not writing queries for each page. This question has nothing to do with pagination. There is simply a considerable number of querysets in the view that are necessary to render the template. The queries are similar in nature, and I am wondering if they can be optimised.